# Use for the phppgadmin Reports Database?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, phppgadmin

[Phppgadmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php?id=start) comes with instructions for creating a reports database on the system for use with phppgadmin. The instructions describe how to set it up, but do not really give any indication of what its purpose is, and the phppgadmin site was not very helpful either.

It seems to allow you to store SQL queries, so is it for storing admin queries accessing tables like `pg_class` etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a standard location to store frequently used SQL scripts.  The reports-pgsql.sql script creates a table for storing these queries, the database they are intended to be run on, a title and some descriptive text about what they do.  PhpPgAdmin has functionality to browse and execute these reports.  It's a pretty simple system just meant to aid in organization.